# Prefect Local Agent Troubleshooting

Tags: python, prefect

I am running a flow on a local agent in docker on EC2 (not ECS). Prefect Cloud is configured to provide a UI for monitoring. The flow executes every 5mins, and for about an hour or so, it does just fine. However, the flows eventually fall behind, before failing to executer entirely and I get the 'cannot find a heartbeat' error.

Is there a way to run the local agent continuously? Why does it suddenly stop?

I apologise for the simplicity of the question, but I am new to Prefect.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the local or docker agent is running within a container itself (rather than a local process), your flow runs end up deployed as containers, but not as individual containers, but rather within the agent container. You effectively have a single agent container spinning up new containers within itself (docker in docker), which may have many unintended consequences such as issues with scale and resource utilization.

To solve this, I would recommend running the local agent as a local process monitored by a supervisord. This [documentation page](https://docs.prefect.io/orchestration/agents/local.html#using-with-supervisor) provides more information.

If you want more environment isolation for this agent process, you can run it within a virtual environment.

To learn more about flow's heartbeat, check out [this page](https://docs.prefect.io/orchestration/agents/local.html#using-with-supervisor) and [this one](https://discourse.prefect.io/t/can-i-run-a-docker-agent-in-a-container/50) for running local or docker agent in a container.

Comment: Thanks for the help. If I understand this page correctly, prefect agent local install will print a suitable supervisord.conf file for me to base my process on, and I can send to a file like so: prefect agent local install > supervisord.conf. I can then make additional edits to file as I need?

Comment: You're spot on, that's exactly how it works!